# d3 v4 outer lines not showing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a d3 chart line chart.  The tick lines are drawing but not the axis lines like so.

```
    this.yAxis = D3.axisLeft(this.yScale).tickPadding(10).tickSize(axisWidth).tickFormat(f);
this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'yaxis')
  .attr('style','stroke-opacity:0.2; stroke: white;stroke-width:2px;')
  .call(this.yAxis)
```

However its not building the chart outer lines. I look at the svg code generated and its not building the paths of class domain either.

I am trying to get the outer lines drawn.  Any suggestions

[image]

Comment: I believe it is X axis that are not drawing border lines. Could you please update the question and include code for X axis?

Comment: While more code would be helpful, see this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c506ac45617cf9ed39337f99f8511218) for what it might be. You have to add grid lines and axis in two parts.